# update nested array object using positional operator

Tags: mongodb

my document object looks like this

```
{ 
   "_id" : ObjectId("5b62cfac2046e98de373399c"),
   "hindi" : {
    "confirmed" : false, 
    "assigned_to" : "xyz+4@abc.com", 
    "candidates" : [

            {
            "candidate_id" : "9262c520-9640-11e8-bfbf-292ac77d55f9", 
            "value" : "स्क्रॉल कैसे करें ?", 
            "createdAt" : NumberInt(1533207154), 
            "createdBy" : "xyz+4@abc.com", 
            "warningList" : [], 
            "comments" : [
                "Correction कैसे स्क्रॉल करें", 
                "added ?"
            ]
           }, 
           {
            "candidate_id" : "297bb060-9642-11e8-ac2d-93ac27f5ee90", 
            "value" : "स्क्रॉल कैसे करें ?", 
            "createdAt" : NumberInt(1533207154), 
            "createdBy" : "xyz+4@abc.com", 
            "warningList" : [], 
            "comments" : [
                "Correction कैसे स्क्रॉल करें", 
                "added ?"
            ]
          }
    ]
}
```

My objective is to find an particular item inside `candidates` array by the `candidate_id` and update the `comment` field.

Here is the query I'm trying with MongoDB `positional operator($)` but getting an error `Unsupported projection option: $set: { hindi.candidates.$.comments: [] }`

```
db.getCollection("strings").update({_id: ObjectId("5b62cfac2046e98de373399c"),"hindi.candidates.candidate_id": "297bb060-9642-11e8-ac2d-93ac27f5ee90"}, {$set :{"hindi.candidates.$.comments" : []}})
```

Comment: Do you want to push something in `comments`array or want to `$set` it as `[]`?

Comment: Correct syntax is `db.getCollection("strings").update(
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5b62cfac2046e98de373399c"),
    "hindi.candidates": { "$elemMatch": { "candidate_id": "297bb060-9642-11e8-ac2d-93ac27f5ee90" } }
  }, 
  { "$set": { "hindi.candidates.$.comments" : [] }}
)`

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet it depends on the requrement, sometimes just needs to be set as empty, sometimes it can contain new values

Comment: you have used incorrect syntax for update query... Try the above one

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet working fine now. could you please elaborate what was the mistakes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) here to match inside an array

```
db.getCollection("strings").update(
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5b62cfac2046e98de373399c"),
    "hindi.candidates": { "$elemMatch": { "candidate_id": "297bb060-9642-11e8-ac2d-93ac27f5ee90" } }
  }, 
  { "$set": { "hindi.candidates.$.comments" : [] }}
)
```